# Array's in function confusion C++

Tags: c++, arrays, function, numbers, average

I need to write a program that is passed an array of int and its size, and with that it prints out the numbers that are above average. Can anyone help clear this question up for me? I am sitting here wondering what the heck it is asking, and I am still quite new to programming so i don't know what to do. Sorry I sound so unable, but I am just confused. Thank you to anybody who can help. This is all I have so far:

Here is the updated code, but I still can't figure out why there aren't multiple average values displaying out, or how to get the output value to be correct.
EDIT: Changed a couple int values in the average() function to floats, but there is still a problem with the total value's at the end

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int average(int values[],int size);

int main(){
int size;
int values[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
cout << "Please input the size of the array" << endl;
cin >> size;
int output = average(values, size);
if(values[size]>output){
    cout << "The values above average are: " << output << endl;
}

return 0;
}

int average(int values[],int size){
float temp=0.0;
for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
    temp += values[i];
}
float end=temp/size;

return end;
}
```

Comment: Go to a library, take many hours to read several books, and come back to your computer. You probably need to read (or initialize) your array, and you might consider using some [std::vector<int>](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/).

Comment: The first step to programming is understanding what you need to do.  Can you describe in words (to yourself) what the task wants?  If you do it well, you'll know how many times you need to look at the array, and a general idea of how to do it.  Then the rest is just learning code.  That's actually the easy part.

Comment: Here is a possible signature for your `average` method. `template<size_t N> int average(const int (&arr)[N])` Take it from there.

Comment: You are calculating the average as a `float` value, which is the Right Thing to do. However, your `average` function returns an `int`, truncating the result towards negative infinity. This doesn't become apparent until you change your predicate for output from `>` to `>=`, ultimately printing some values **below** average (`3` in your example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your supposed to create an array of intigers and pass it to the average function, and need to pass the size(so that you know how many times to loop). In the loop in your Average function add all the values to a temporary value, then divide by the count input-ed to the function.

```
//returns the average
int average(int Values[],int Size){
    //perhaps declare a temporary value here
    for(int i=0;i<Size;i++){
        //add all the values up and store in a temporary value
    }
    //here divide by Size and return that as the average
}
```

this

```
if(values[size]>output){
    cout << "The values above average are: " << output << endl;
}
```

should be replaced with something like:

```
for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
    if(values[i]>output){
        cout << "The values above average are: " << values[i] << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Everything is very clear and simple to me. Thank you

Comment: So i worked on it and I came out with this, but it doesn't come out as multiple integers or any averages... It is updated above, could you take a look if you get a chance?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a less convoluted solution than those posted. Main feature: It actually does do what it should:

```
#include <iostream>

template<size_t N>
float average( const int (&value)[N] ) {
    float total( 0.0f );
    // Sum all values
    for ( size_t index = 0; index < N; ++index )
        total += value[index];
    // And divide by the number of items
    return ( total / N );
}

int main() {
    int value[]  = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
    // Calculate average value
    float avg = average( value );
    const size_t count = ( sizeof( value ) / sizeof( value[0] ) );
    // Iterate over all values...
    for ( size_t index = 0; index < count; ++index )
        // ... and print those above average
        if ( value[index] > avg )
            std::cout << value[index] << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Live example at [Ideone](http://ideone.com/gSAt0z). Output:

```
4
5
6
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, but its just too complicated for what I am working on at the moment. I appreciate it though. XenoZergNid is right on the dot with the simple wording and code.

Comment: @user You'll change your mind once you find out that your average is *sometimes* wrong.